# Extract emails from word is returning empty values, what is wrong? python

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

When I run this code, I'm not getting any emails shown, could this be because the emails are in a table in word, or is it another problem?

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
import re

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\test')
path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\test'
output_path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\test1'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}/docx_emails.xlsx'.format(output_path),engine='xlsxwriter')

data = []  

regex = re.compile(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+')
for filename in list(os.listdir(path)):
    wordDoc = Document(os.path.join(path, filename))
    documentText = '\n'.join([p.text for p in wordDoc.paragraphs])
    match = regex.findall(documentText)
    data.append(match)
    
   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

print(df)
```

returning:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]

[488 rows x 0 columns]
```

The documentText looks like this:

```
Background
About
PYX Financial Group is an investment holding company which provides capital management service to corporate clients.
Snapshot
Address
Full Allocation Breakdown
Allocations
Contacts - 
1 known contact
Fund Portfolio Breakdown - Private Equity
Primary Fund Focus
Fund Type
Fund Portfolio - - Private Equity - 5 known funds
Fund Manager Relationships - - Private Equity - 1 known fund manager
Investment Overview - Private Equity
Fund Types
Private Equity
Buyout
Buyout fund size: Mid Cap, Large Cap
Locations & Markets
Europe, North America, West Europe
Industries
Business Services, Diversified, Energy, Financial Services, Healthcare, Industrial, Life Sciences, Manufacturing, Media, Technology, Telecoms
Summary
PYX Financial Group is an investor in the private equity asset class.
Preferences
PYX Financial Group's portfolio consists of buyout vehicles managed by Carlyle Group. It favours a diversified range of industries, including technology, energy, medical technology, media, manufacturing, business services, telecoms ad financial services. Geographically, it has a preference for the European market as well as the US.
Buyout Deals Breakdown - Private Equity
Location
Primary Industry
Investment Type
Deal Size
Buyout Deals Exposure - - Private Equity - 175 known deals from fund investments
Investment Overview - Natural Resources
Locations & Markets
West Europe
Route to Market
Strategies
Industries
Summary
PYX Financial Group is an investor in natural resources.
Preferences
PYX Financial Group gains access to the asset class via unlisted vehicles. It targets the energy sector focusing on the west European market, including France, Germany and the UK.
Allocation Breakdown - Natural Resources
Natural Resources Breakdown
```

What's causing the dataframe to be empty, or why aren't emails being included in the documentText? I have already extracted the tables that are relevant in the document, and the emails are shown in these tables, but were not extracted along with them, and I'm not sure why, I assumed it's because they're not actually part of the tables are classed as text - so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you printed the values of `match` and `documentText` to see if there's anything? Have you tested your regex against some of the text in isolation to make sure it works?

Comment: @wkl yes, I don't think that the email string is being recognized as text in paragraphs. `match` is empty too, though documentText has a lot of text in. regex works when I use something other than the email - how can identify what the email is being contained in if not paragraphs or tables?

Comment: You're going to have to provide examples of what this documentText looks like, like snippets with emails in it (you can fake the emails but the format of your data should be the same).

Comment: How can I provide it? (I'm new to posting here

Comment: Get a snippet of your `documentText` by, say, printing it out in your code, edit it down/remove sensitive info, and then edit your post and add a new code block with the text.

Comment: I've put it in now, its all public info so not sensitive. I can't figure out why the tables or paragraph neither contain the emails.

Comment: Oh, I now see what the potential issue is. If all your emails are only contained in tables, you need to access [`document.tables`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.tables) and then get all text from their row cells.

Comment: I tried to extract it from tables already - it extracts everything apart from the emails from the table. The email cells just remain empty, any idea why?